# Laravel 5.2, file_get_contents with looping for all files. How with blade?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to take the entire contents of files in 
`resources\views\angularTemplates`  folder

I did before something like that for a single file and with `asset()` function :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="defult-icons">
  {!! file_get_contents(asset('assets/img/defult_icons.svg')); !!}
</script>
```

But Now I want to make, for a **whole folder** in `resources\views`

And get in every interaction in a loop - **the current file's name**

Say something like that:

```
  @loop('views\angularTemplates', $file_name, $file_content)

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="{!! $file_name !!}">  
        {!! $file_content !!}
    </script>

  @endloop
```

There is a way to do it with blade way ?

Comment: So what's the problem you are trying to solve here with this `file_get_contents()` thing?

Comment: Because I want to do this in resources\views\ with loop. And most importantly: get the file name each interaction

Comment: I don't understand, what will that loop do?

Comment: including Angualr templates to a main page

Comment: You are trying to achieve something impossible and most likely a very bad idea. I can't help you with this problem but I can only tell you to go learn a little bit more about Angular and Laravel.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this :
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache
But, Instead of doing it in Angular with http request.for each template. 
I want to make it in a server with including. 

I hope this is more understandable

Comment: Why? Do it with Gulp / Grunt, it's a front end thing, your server shouldn't care about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I did this. If someone will have :

```
   <?php

      $path = base_path('resources\views\includes\angular-templates\\');
      $templates = File::allFiles($path);

    ?>

    @foreach ($templates as $template)

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="{!! $template->getBasename() !!}">
          {!! file_get_contents( $path . $template->getBasename() ) !!}
        </script>

    @endforeach
```